# search Unicode Text in Stored Procedure Using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I wrote the following stored procedure in SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2008:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchName]
    @Name nvarchar(5)=''
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tblNames WHERE FirstName=N'@Name'
END
```

I need to search by Unicode text. For example, if I call this procedure with '`فارسی`', the stored procedure should run this: `FirstName=N'فارسی'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchName]

    @Name NVARCHAR(5) = N''

AS BEGIN

    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.tblNames 
    WHERE FirstName = @Name

END
```